# How to enable history in Django shell in python

Tags: python, django, centos

I am using `shell_plus` for my Django shell.

The `readline` and `rlcompleter` modules are installed there.

But I find that when I close my `shell_plus` session, I can return to the history commands I used in previous sessions.

In my office, I can go back to previous commands as well.

what do I need to do for that?

Answer (score 8):

You could use bpython it has history enabled and many other fantastic features, if you are using virtualenv install it with pip.

```
pip install bpython
```

or globally

```
apt-get install bpython
```

For me this is the most amazing interactive shell for python.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have [`IPython`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#history) installed?

The [docs mention](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/docs/shell_plus.rst#interactive-python-shells) that

> The default resolution order is: bpython, ipython, python.

P.S. I haven't used bpython but there [seems to be a history](http://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/configuration.html#hist-file) too.

Comment: i have ipython installed. how can i check if shell is using simple python or ipython. i am using virtuslenv

Comment: And is IPython installed globally or in your virtualenv as well? Your can use IPython explicitly by starting shell_plus like this ```./manage.py shell_plus --use-ipython```.

Comment: i get this error `manage.py: error: no such option: --use-ipython`

Comment: Ah, sorry, the syntax seems to have changed. 
It's ``shell_plus --ipython``. See ``--help`` for all available options.

Comment: Python3.4 and above has history and tab completion by default, but this does not seem to work with `./manage.py shell`, even if it uses the same python version.

Comment: `pip install ipython` did the trick. Maybe edit in this exact command to make the post more direct.

Answer (score -1):

Try out `shell_plus`, which comes in [`django-extensions`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions).

```bash
(venv) ➜ pip install django-extensions
```

Then install [`ipython`](https://ipython.org/) or [`bypython`](https://www.bpython-interpreter.org/):

```bash
(venv) ➜ pip install ipython
```

or

```bash
(venv) ➜ pip install bpython
```

So now you should add `django-extensions` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_extensions',
    ...
)
```

Also, Add the below config to your `settings.py` module and above the `INSTALLED_APPS` config:

```py
SHELL_PLUS = "ipython" # or "bpython" if you installed bpython
```

Then by running the below command you get history, colors, auto-imports, and more sorts of good stuff in your Django shell:

```bash
(venv) ➜ python manage.py shell_plus
```

Also, you can run the shell_plus with another interpreter each time you want by using its name with your command for example:

```bash
(venv) ➜ python manage.py shell_plus --bpython
```

And If you want to use [`ipython notebook`](https://ipython.org/notebook.html) your command should be like this:

```bash
(venv) ➜ python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```