# Django shell history commands always come from top

Tags: django, ipython, django-extensions

I've been having issues in trying to use older Django shell history commands, be it from previous shell session or current.

If I press UP arrow key, they show the first lines in the ~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite, and not the last one I pressed enter on.

A couple of things I've tried are:

1. Removed ipython history file, touched it again but same problem.
2. Re-installed Ipython in venv.
3. Tried using shell from a different project.
4. Tried using shell_plus from django-extensions.

Nothing seemed to fix the issue. Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: Did you tried from command prompt or terminal?

Comment: I'm using Archlinux, so using terminal. Using different terminals dont seem to fix it either.

Comment: does this help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-home-end-tab-complete-keys-not-working-in-shell

Comment: Thank you for the link but it doesnt help sorry :( I can use arrow keys and it does go up commands, but instead of going up 1 command, it goes up to the first command i entered when the shell's history.sqlite was created.

Comment: Are you using django.

Comment: Yep. Using Django.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377452/how-to-enable-history-in-django-shell-in-python